# setting focus on fb app for up, down arrow key

Tags: facebook, focus

My fb app requires users to press up and down arrow key. it works well when on an independent page, but when i integrate it on fb, the problem is, when the user presses up or down arrow key, the fb page scrolls up or down. There should be a solution to this. Kindly suggest.

Comment: i have used "a" "s" "d" "w" as of now instead of  left down right up. but still looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the focus on loading the iframe in Facebook is on the actual page and not the iframe.  The following javascript code should prevent the parent page from scrolling.

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
    if (keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) {
        return false;
    }
};
```